# Lower bound on multiplication

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis, multiplication

I was told that the fastest possible algorithm for integer multiplication is $O\left(n{\log}(n)\right)$. Why would this so?
 
Can you please show why the fastest multiplication algorithm would have such a time complexity?

Comment: Where did you get this lower bound information? Are you sure it represents the *theoretical* lower bound for *all possible* algorithms?

Comment: What exactly are you multiplying?

Comment: Where did you get that idea from (your claim about the running time of multiplication)?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Lower_bounds, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCrer%27s_algorithm.

Comment: @D.W. Furer's algorithm and the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm, are both $O\left(n\log(n)\right)$. As for where I got $O\left(n\log(n)\right)$ as the lower bound for multiplication, it was from this stack exchange. I posted some questions about multiplication algorithms last year, and a few members mentioned the lower bound for multiplication.

Comment: @juho Integer multiplication.

Comment: @TobiAlafin, no, these algoritms take time bigger than $O(n\log n)$. Also, it's a conjecture that multiplication can't be done faster in that time. The only known bound is $\Omega(n)$.

Comment: @TobiAlafin, no, the running time of Furer's algorithm and the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm is not $O(n \log n)$.  Where did you read that?    I suggest you do a bit more research, and read the links I gave you, as you seem to have gotten some incorrect information from somewhere.  It would help if you could link to the source of the information and where you got those beliefs from.  If you're relying on memory, your memory might be faulty.

Comment: @D.W. I meant $O(n\log(n)) = o(f(x)) = o(g(x))$, where $f(x)$ is the time complexity Schönhage–Strassen algorithm and $g(x)$ is the time complexity of Fuhrer's algorithm. They are both asymptotically worse than $O(n\log(n))$. As for the $O(n\log(n)), I was given that figure in this stack exchange.

Comment: To show that they are worse you need to use $\omega(n\log n)$. To show that they are not better than it, you need to use $\Omega(n\log n)$.

Comment: While it is conjectured that integer multiplication is $\Omega(n\log n)$, there are no non-trivial lower bounds known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication of n-bit integers can be done in $O (n \log n)$ if you are a bit careless in calculating the complexity, for example using convolution and FFT. You need $O (n \log n)$ floating point operations, but as n grows larger, you need to increase (very slowly) the precision of the floating-point operations, which will increase the complexity a little bit.

It is very well possible that no algorithm can be faster than $O (n \log n)$. It is a bit more possible that we will never find such an algorithm. However, I'm not aware of anything coming even close to a proof.

Proofs for lower bounds that turn out to be actually achieved are usually either very simple or nonexistent. For example the proof that sorting n items using comparisons takes $O(n \log n)$ is quite simple. When someone writes "multiplication cannot be done faster than $O(n \log n)$", that most likely means "I have not the slightest idea how this could be done".

Comment: In which computation model can you multiply integers in $O(n\log n)$?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [lower bound](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10935) for multiplication of $\Omega(n\log{n})$ conditional on a conjecture in network coding. There is also an [algorithm](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document) matching this bound.

Comment: This is a *circuit size* lower bound. It does not translate to any nontrivial lower bound on the running time of, say, multitape Turing machines.

Comment: oh I see, thanks!