# Multiplication algorithm I wrote - slower than I expected

Tags: algorithms, python, multiplication

Recently I thought of an algorithm for multiplication and decided to stop dreaming and start writing on paper my ideas, and even implement this to code (in this case - Python 3.9.1).
I do not know if it resembles Karatsuba's algorithm, but I glanced at it and it seems to work very differently.

---

The idea behind this multiplication (calculating $x \cdot y$) algorithm is to represent them as a power of two, plus some remainder, then use the distributive rule of multiplication to get:

$$x = 2^a + K  \\ y = 2^b + T$$

$$ x \cdot y = (2^a + K) \cdot (2^b + T) = 2^{a+b} + T \cdot2^a + K \cdot 2^b  + K \cdot T$$

I chose the power to be $2$ as it would help us with bit-manipulation later on.
Calculating $2^{a+b}$ is easy using bitwise operations as so: $$ 2^{a+b} = 1 << (a+b)$$

### But how would we find $a$ and $b$?

We want $2^a$ or $2^b$ to be the largest power of $2$ below our $x$ (or $y$ correspondingly), to take as much *'volume'* from the original number, and thus making the calculations easier with bit manipulations. So, I just used the $\lg$ function, which from what I've read it can run in [$O(1)$ running-time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317414/what-is-the-complexity-of-the-log-function) (Or at worst, $\lg \lg n$). We have:

$$ a = \lfloor \lg(x) \rfloor, ~~~ b = \lfloor \lg(y) \rfloor$$

We then need to find $K$ which is just the remainder when we subtract $2^a$ from $x$: $$K= x - 2^a = x - (1 << a)$$

However, maybe subtraction isn't the best idea, maybe it takes too much time, and though about another bit manipulation. All I had to do is to flip the most significant bit (left most bit) which represents the greatest power of $2$ this number consists of, and so I had to pad exactly $a$ $1$'s and use the $\&$ bitwise operation to clear the MSB. We now have a code to find $K$ and $T$ respectively:

$$ K = x~~ \&~~ \text{int('1' * a, 2)} \\ T = y~~ \&~~ \text{int('1' * b, 2)}$$

Finally, we can add all the factors together, calling the function recursively to compute $K \cdot T$ to get:

$$ (1 << (a + b)) + (T << a) + (K << b) + \overbrace{\text{mult(K,T)}}^{\text{recursive call}}$$

---

```
def mult(x, y):
    if x == 1:
        return y
    elif y == 1:
        return x
    elif x == 0 or y == 0:
        return 0

    base_x = int(log2(x))
    base_y = int(log2(y))

    K = x & int('1' * base_x, 2)
    T = y & int('1' * base_y, 2)

    return (1 << (base_x + base_y)) + (T << base_x) + (K << base_y) + mult(K, T)
```

---

But oh! from what I've tested, this algorithm does not seem to get near the time it takes to multiply two numbers by just using the plain-old $\text{*}$ operation, Sob!

```
times = []
for _ in range(10000):
    x = random.randint(10 ** 900, 10 ** 1000)
    y = random.randint(10 ** 900, 10 ** 1000)
    start = time.time()
    mult(x, y)
    end = time.time()
    times.append(end - start)
print(sum(times)/len(times))
```

This tests $1,000$ multiplications of $900$ to $1000$ digits long random integers, then printing the average time. On my machine the average is: `0.01391555905342102` seconds. Python's regular multiplication won't even show a number, just `0.0` because it is so fast.

From what I know, Python's algorithm [uses Karatsuba's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957363/why-is-pythons-built-in-multiplication-so-), and it is roughly $O(n^{\approx 1.58})$ - I did not analyze mine strictly, but in one sense it runs at approximately: $$O(\max (\text{#Number_of_on_bits_x, #Number_of_on_bits_y}))$$
Because every recursive call, we turn off the $\text{MSB}$ - thus the number of recursive calls we make is the maximum number of bits that are **on** ($=1$) in $x$ and $y$, which is strictly smaller than the numbers themselves.. thus we can surely say it is $O(\max (x,y)) \sim O(n)$ as all the other operations in the functions are $O(1)$. So it boils down to the question of 'why?' - why is it slower? What have I done wrong in my algorithm so it is slower even that from first glance it seems faster?

Thank you!

Comment: Let's assume that $x$ and $y$ are numbers of length $n$. The recurrence for running time of your algorithm is $T(n) = c n + T(n-1)$, and the solution for the recurrence is $O(n^2)$. Since $10^8$ operations take usually $0.1-1$ sec, I say that the result is expected (with Python these numbers are usually multiplied by $10-100$, but, luckily for you, you use standard built-in functions for the heavy stuff, so you've avoided that).

Comment: @Dmitry But how come we say it is $O(n^2)$ when we talk about the *length* of the numbers, not the *magnitude* of them. Because $10^{900}$ is a large number when talking about magnitude, but it is only $901$ digits long!

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The running time is $O(n^2)$, where $n$ is the length of the number. What do you disagree with?

Comment: @Dmitry We are measuring the running time by the length of the numbers or the *magnitude* when talking about multiplication algorithms? I don't understand why, in this algorithm, the worst case is when all the numbers are represented in binary as many $1$'s ($1111111 \dots $) what is important here is the magnitude no? how we deal with very large numbers (not in length, but in size!) In this algorithm, multiplying 2 huge numbers $\sim ~ 10^{900}$ only takes $|900|$ recursive calls, which is way way smaller than the *actual* number (itself!)

Comment: I think I got you, we need to talk about the number of *digits*, not the actual size of $n$. Sob!  Is there a known lower bound of multiplying two integers together? like we have in sorting (comparison-based algorithms $\Omega (n \lg n)$ ) ? Thank you sir. @Dmitry

Comment: We measure running time w.r.t. input size. I.e., in this case, with respect to the number of digits. This is why factorization is (probably) a hard problem: you can factorize number $a$ in $\sqrt a$ time, but in terms of the number of digits it's $2^{\frac n 2}$ time. This is important in cryptography, since it means that you can produce small inputs (only $1000$ digits long) which are hard to factorize. Anyway, you were comparing with Karatsuba, and $n^{1.58}$ is also w.r.t. length of the number (number of digits).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the field. Looks like there is some conditional lower bound and the matching upper bound: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/134653/114966

Comment: Wait, I think I don't fully understand one thing, why is it $O(n^2)$ - we call the function $\text{Mult}$ only when the number can be represented with $2^a + K$ this is only the number of $1$'s that appear in its binary form, and we don't need to take into account the second number, only the one with the largest amount of $1$'s no?

Comment: Hi @fastttt, your algorithm could be quick if you can send a recursive call that does all calculations "in place".  In other words, if you don't send a _copy_ of $K$ and $T$, but use the input without copying it.  The state of the art is that very recently, within a year or so, a paper with a time of $O(n \log{(n)})$ was submitted: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02070778/document  The problem I see is that you'd have to update a pointer to the end of the input that you're examining, and that could take $O(\log{(n)})$ time.

Comment: @MattGroff Hi, can you please elaborate on the copies of $K$ and $T$ I did not quite understand that, and also that paper is simply beautiful I will try to go over it! Thank you sir!

Comment: Consider multiplication of numbers `111...1` of length $n$. Then $x = y = 2^{n-1} + K$, where $K$ is `111...11` of length $n-1$. So in the worst case, you call mult for every digit.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes but on every digit in the *binary representation* and a number is represented in $\lg n$ digits, not $n$. No?

Comment: Your idea is to make a recursive call using the updated $K$ and $T$, right?  Well, where do these $K$ and $T$ come from?  If you make a copy of them, you're copying up to $n$ bits every time you do a recursive call.  Summing these numbers, $n$, $n-1$, $n-2$, ... will take $O(n^2)$ time.  So I believe that you want to use the same copy repeatedly, with pointers to the current bit.  But that's the problem.  You're summing $k$ and $T$ repeatedly, which takes time $O(n^2)$.

Comment: No. When we talk about running time, we always talk about the size of the input, i.e. the number of digits. I.e. $n$ is the number of digits. And the number itself is between $2^{n-1}$ and $2^{n}$. If it's more convenient for you, we can talk about the number $x$ itself. Then the running time is $O(\log^2 x)$, which is exactly the same thing. Then for Karatsuba the running time is $O(\log^{1.58} x)$.